# What limitations, if any, are there on what kind of concepts can be declared using RDF?

Tags: rdf, ontology

I wanted to ask about limitations on the "concepts" that can be defined using RDF or OWL. Some concepts such as the economic term "inflation" or the concept "overwork" (as when someone works too much) come to mind as more abstract examples.

(This would be in the context of creating a [triplestore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore) of structured information for the purpose of training an AI.)

Are there known limitations on what kind of "concepts" can be defined using RDF?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070602/what-are-the-limits-to-expressability-of-rdf-owl-etc